# TeXLipse, Pygments and the minted package not working

Tags: minted, texlipse

I've got a little problem to get minted working on Mac OS X 10.8.3.

Things I've installed:

- minted 1.7 (was already installed via TeX Live Utility)
- Python 2.7
- Pygments 1.6 (is in $PATH environment and can be called from everywhere in the terminal)

For writing TeX-Code I'm using the Eclipse Plugin TeXLipse. For generating PDF output it uses XeLaTeX with the "--shell-escape" argument.

For the following code i get the error message:

```
Package minted Error: You must have `pygmentize' installed to use this package.
```

The minimal code is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}

\section{My sourcecode}
Code

\end{document}
```

Maybe someone has an idea how to get minted working. Thanks for that!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On my system, `pygmentize` is in `/usr/local/bin`; it's possible that Eclipse doesn't have this directory in its path.

Comment: You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. On my system the location of pygmentize is also /usr/local/bin. Do you know how to add a path to the Eclipse path?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Eclipse itself rather than any TeX-specific Eclipse issues.


Comment: Just in case anyone else stumbles upon this question searching for a solution:
1) you have to add `-shell-escape` to the exact program you are using with TeXlipse.
This can be in a standard setup either
`Window -> Preferences -> Texlipse -> Builder Settings -> Latex program`
or
`... -> PdfLatex program`
for example.
2) you have to add the path to the `pygmentize` executable in
`Window -> Preferences -> Texlipse -> Builder Settings -> Environment`
Find Path: `which pygmentize` in a terminal, or just `Import` the PATH variable if you are able to call `pygmentize` in a terminal already.